# How is it possible to extract substring based on regex in linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, git

The `git submodule status | grep yourSubmodule` command gives one of these results:

```
+1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1 yourSubmodule (remotes/origin/HEAD)
 1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1 yourSubmodule (remotes/origin/HEAD)
```

I would like to extract the hash from the result. I created a regex, which captures the hash in a group:

```
^(?:\+|\s)([0-9a-z]+)\syourSubmodule\s
```

How is it possible to use it in the shell? Maybe the grep is not even needed. I've found the documentation of `sed` command, but it is very confusing.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```
git submodule status | awk '/yourSubmodule/{print $1}'
```

Output:

```
+1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1
1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1
```

or with `+` and space as field separator:

```
git submodule status | awk -F '[+ ]' '/yourSubmodule/{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1
1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution to the problem, and a reminder that not every problem that involves strings needs regular expressions for parsing.  Sometimes the built-in field-handling of many Unix tools is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

*How is it possible to use it in the shell? Maybe the grep is not even needed.* Using Bash's `=~` operator (emulating `git` with `cat` below, not forcing useless use of it):

```
$ cat file | 
for stdin in /dev/stdin
do 
    while IFS= read -r line
    do [[ "$line" =~ yourSubmodule ]] && 
       [[ "$line" =~ [a-f0-9]{40} ]] && 
       echo $BASH_REMATCH
    done < "$stdin"
done
```

Output:

```
1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1
1b2377f523dca6fa0c49bd7fa56eeb32011774e1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of constructing the whole list, just ask for what you want directly:

```
git rev-parse :path/to/submodule      # what's recorded for it
git -C path/to/submodule rev-parse @  # what's there now
```